# Rewriting URL at the center

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this original url

```
http://localhost:88/coloragon/welcome.php
```

By using the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^.*hi/?$  welcome.php
```

I am able to access above original url using following rewritten url

```
http://localhost:88/coloragon/hi
```

But

By using following rule

```
RewriteRule ^.*mycoloragon.*/?$  coloragon
```

Why i am not able to access original url using following rewritten url

```
http://localhost:88/mycoloragon/welcome.php
```

Comment: as per my knowledge you can not access original url. htaccess rules are override completely original url to new url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using this rule from '/coloragon/` directory:

```
RewriteRule ^.*mycoloragon.*/?$ coloragon
```

therefore `http://localhost:88/mycoloragon/welcome.php` won't work because it will rewrite your URL to: `http://localhost:88/coloragon/mycoloragon/`.

Remember `.htaccess` is per directory directive.

**Solution:** if you want `http://localhost:88/mycoloragon/welcome.php` URL then use this rule in **root .htaccess**:

```
RewriteRule ^mycoloragon(/.*)?$ /coloragon$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It sounds pretty convincing. But after i placed htaccess haing following text `RewriteEngine On (then next line)
RewriteRule ^mycoloragon/?$ /coloragon [L,NC]` at root directory. `http://localhost:88/mycoloragon/welcome.php` still not wroking

Comment: Surprisingly the rule `^mycoloragon/?$ /coloragon [L,NC]` is redirecting this url `http://localhost:88/mycoloragon/welcome.php` to `http://localhost:88/coloragon/` rather than translating it into `http://localhost:88/coloragon/welcome.php`

Comment: There is no redirect flag used in my rule. Did you try updated rule? I need to run for a meeting, will check this thread in an hour.

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine now. It was some cache problem